# How do I create a pie chart that displays the quantity of something registered by each someone?

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

In my project, I want to display in the pie chart how many institutions each employee registered in the system.
The institutions table contains a foreign key with the id of the employee who registered the institution, so every institution has an employee associated with it.

I built the following code, but couldn't go further:

```
//etc

    String query = "SELECT i.ins_id, f.fun_nome FROM instituicao i " +
                "JOIN funcionario f " +
                "ON(f.fun_id = i.ins_fun_id)";

        PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoDAO.con.prepareStatement(query,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        total = rs.getInt(1);
    }

    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

    for(VFuncionarioVO vo : lista) {
        //pieDataset.setValue(vo.getNome(), );
    }

//etc
```

I tried using GROUP BY in the query, but that didn't solve the problem.

**EDIT**: actually, using the GROUP BY statement is necessary for this job. Please read the accepted answer and its commentaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `PreparedStatement`. Use the [`org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCPieDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCPieDataset.html) constructor that accepts a query "that returns data in two columns, the first containing `VARCHAR` data, and the second containing numerical data." You can use the dataset in your `ChartFactory`.

```
JDBCPieDataset ds = new JDBCPieDataset(conn, "SELECT ...");
```

A complete example is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/ce4137a5b6015de88662c43c463add45).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try using it and post the result later.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now, but I had to modify my SQL query a little, since the setValue method from JDBCPieDataset accepts first a String then a numerical value, so:
String query = "SELECT f.fun_nome, COUNT(i.ins_id) FROM instituicao i JOIN funcionario f ON(f.fun_id = i.ins_fun_id) GROUP BY f.fun_nome";

Comment: Also, I had to do the following, before this.add(new ChartPanel(chart)), to display the raw values in the chart (not the percentage, which is shown by the tooltip): PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot(); PieSectionLabelGenerator generator = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} = {1}", new DecimalFormat("0"), new DecimalFormat("0")); plot.setLabelGenerator(generator);