# JFreeChart not displaying data from MySQL correctly

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart, pie-chart

I have a mysql table 'tweetresponses' with a column 'sentiment' which stores an int between 1-4.  My pie chart using JFreeChart should display how many times an int between 1-4 is stored.

My code currently is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection();

    Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * From tweetresponses");
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

    while(resultSet.next()) {
         dataset.setValue( 
         resultSet.getString("sentiment"),
         Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("sentiment")));
      }

      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
         "Sentiment of Tweets: ",  // chart title           
         dataset,         // data           
         true,            // include legend          
         true,           
         false);

      int width = 560; /* Width of the chart */
      int height = 370; /* Height of the chart */ 
      File pieChart = new File( "Chart.jpeg" );
      ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG( pieChart , chart , width , height );
   }
```

[Here is the pie chart that is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xku8E.jpg)

Comment: Im hoping to represent 1 as very negative, 4 as very positive etc

Comment: Try `JDBCPieDataset`; possible duplicate of [*How do I create a pie chart that displays the quantity of something registered by each someone?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16704595/230513).